# check if an element is being hovered over

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to check if a element is being hovered over. I get this error:

```
Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: hover
```

when I use this code:

```
 $('.class').blur(function(){
    if(!$(this).is(':hover')){
       //element not being hovered over
    }
 });
```

i also tried this:

```
 $('.class').blur(function(){
    if($(this+":hover").length === 0){ 
       //element not being hovered over
    }
 });
```

this also does not work. Is there any other way of doing this. Thanks.

Comment: Which jQuery version are you using? This was buggy in jq 1.9.x. Be aware though, this still doesn't work if matched set returns more than one element, in any jq version AFAIK **but** `if(!$(this).is(':hover'))` would work on 1.10.0 e.g

Comment: I am using 1.9.x because I want support for ie6/7/8

Comment: Upgrade to 1.11.x  (lastest one?), it still support ie6/7/9, only 2.x branch has removed support

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".class").mouseover(function(){   
    $(this).attr('checked',true);   
    });  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**jQuery has this functionality built-in.** [See documentation on .hover()](https://api.jquery.com/hover/)

```
$(".class").hover(
  function() {
    // item is being hovered over
    $(this).addClass('hover');
  }, function() {
    // item is no longer being hovered over
    $(this).removeClass('hover');
  }
);
```